# Casting from JTable Object to int

Tags: java, swing, casting, jtable, int

I am attempting to retrieve a value from a JTable and am getting a java.lang.nullpointer exception.  The following line seems to be the issue.  I am trying to get it to take the object, which is 25, and basically cast it to int.  For some reason this simple task seems to be extremely difficult or impossible.  I looked at another StackOverflow users question with a similar problem but he never got a response that worked.

The error codes read as follows:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Gradebook$5.actionPerformed(Gradebook.java:925)THIS IS THE SECOND LINE IN THE LOOP.

NOTE: I EDITED THIS POST TO PROVIDE ADDITIONAL CODE.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                myClass[currentClass].getCategoryElement(i).setName((String)categoriesTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1));
                myClass[currentClass].getCategoryElement(i).setWeight(Integer.valueOf((String)(categoriesTable.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2))));//THIS LINE IS THE IDENTIFIED PROBLEM
            }

 categoriesTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {"1", "Classwork", "20"},
            {"2", "Homework", "20"},
            {"3", "Tests", "20"},
            {"4", "Quizzes", "20"},
            {"5", "Projects", "20"},
            {"6", null, null},
            {"7", null, null},
            {"8", null, null},
            {"9", null, null},
            {"10", null, null},
        },
```

Comment: "NullPointerException" means one of those 5 objects was null.  We can't guess which without more code.

Comment: 1. `NOTE: I EDITED THIS POST TO PROVIDE ADDITIONAL CODE.` == for better help soner post an SSCCE/MCVE , short, runnable, compilable, 2. search for `getColumnClass to avoids the casting

Comment: Separate your statements (instead of one long method chain) and do null checks, because you _do_ have null values? And why would you want to store your integer values as Strings? Just save them as integers. If this is numeric data, doesn't it make more sense?

Comment: If I do a null check then what do you recommend that I store as the int value in the object?  And, to my understanding the integer values in the JTable are automatically objects and those objects cannot be converted/cast to int directly...they must first be converted/cast to String.

Comment: @Daron: First: use the class java.lang.Integer. That's an object representing an Integer. Second: the line throwing the exception could have 5 different values being null. So, split this line into multiple, smaller instructions; store the result in a variable that you pass to the next one. I.e. instead of doing `foo.getBar().setBaz()`, do `Bar bar = foo.getBar(); bar.setBaz();`

Comment: `Object[] { 1 }` will be autoboxed and you can cast that value to `Integer` if you need to `Object val = getValueAt(..); if (val instancof Integer)` <- will return true. Try it. I may not get your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping me.  I ultimately used an if statement to check for null values though I'm still not sure why I didn't need to do the same thing for the first statement in the loop.

Comment: Both column 1 and 2 have nulls. And you're using `getValueAt(i, 1)` and `getValueAt(i, 2)`. The NPE doesn't occur until the first row with a null value